# Why does this regex execute slowly?

Tags: javascript, regex

So i've got a regex that identifies URLs:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

But when I use it to identify urls that a user has entered, simply using `.test` slows the page down considerably, even though according to the [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org), it's [supposed to be faster than exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description). Am I using an outdated method of testing Regular Expressions? Is there a faster method that i don't know about? or is my regex just really long and complicated?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sVX9/).

Edit:
Takes 20.7 seconds in Chrome, v24
1:48.5 in Internet Explorer 9

Comment: It executes quickly for me with Firefox 18.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, v24.

Comment: `([\/\w \.-]*)*` <-- Backtracking hell, with 2 layers of `*`. I read somewhere that Firefox implements some limit.

Comment: Nice catch nhahtdh; removing the second `*` fixes the execution time in Chrome.  I wonder if Firefox is designed to catch cases of backtracking, since it appears to have similar execution times whether the second layer of `*` is present or not.

Comment: @Vulcan: It is also possible that the implementation of the regex does something smart to remove extra layer of backtracking (it is totally possible for the "*theoretically* regular" portions of the expression, what I means is not including those look-around, backreference, etc.). I am not sure of the details, though.

Comment: it only slows down when i use a url that has posted information, like ".php?something"

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the regex only lags when it processes a url that has posted information, for example in the jsfiddle url `Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811139009`. When that part of the url is removed, the regex preforms correctly, and quickly.

However, removing the last star from `([\/\w \.-]*)*` makes the regex preform incorrectly, so using `([\/\w \.-]*)` is not an option.

Rather, for the regex to be able to handle urls with posted information, the last part needs to be removed:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

to

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*/
```

this is because the regex is designed to detect filetypes or a backslash at the end of the url, not a question mark and posted information. removing the last part fixes the problem and the regex runs correctly **and** quickly.